# How to restore row data on cancelled update

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

I'm using the Angularjs version 1 edition of the ui-grid.  I set the rows to NOT automatically save, allowing me to use a button click to fire off an angularjs call that uses $http to update the database.

If the user clicks the Cancel Update button, I instead want to reset the row to its original data and state.  I have code that uses the `setRowsClean(dataRows)` and I also can pass in the row object and set `row.isDirty = false`.

I am looking for a proven technique that will let me reset the row's data and its state to be the same as it was prior to the cancelled changes.  Rebinding the grid is overkill and causes the grid to collapse.  Does anyone have something working along these lines?

Comment: what about to reload the entire list?

Comment: In what way do you mean to reload the entire list?

Comment: If you have a variable $scope.list, for example, and the user has inserted new items, removed others, updated others... and then, the user clicks on "Cancel Update", I would run the $http again to reload $scope.list